# How to access local appsettings in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, configuration, azure-functions

I'm really struggling to find how to access the App Settings from an instance created in an Azure Function.

I have the following code...

```
namespace ThingServiceFunctionApp
{    
    public static class RoleFunctions
    {
        [FunctionName("GetThings")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "roles")]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            return await FunctionApp.GetFunction<IGetThingsFunction>().RunAsync(req, log).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }


    public static class FunctionApp
    {
        private static readonly IFunctionFactory FuncFactory = new FunctionFactory(new Startup());

        public static IFunction GetFunction<TFunction>() where TFunction : IFunction
        {
            return FuncFactory.Create<TFunction>();
        }
    }


     public class Startup : IStartup
     {

          private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

          public Startup()
          {
              Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                  .Build();
          }


          public IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
          {
              services
                  .AddSingleton<IThingService, ThingService>()
                  .AddTransient<IGetThingsFunction, GetThings>();

              return services;
          } 
        }
      }
  }
```

How can I access values from Configuration from within the ThingService or GetThings function?

Not relevant but FYI I have added my own support for DI (code not shown) - hence the .AddSingleton etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use your `Configuration` (passing it to the right spot)? What's the problem?

Comment: Hi that is a good point - however as far as I remember in a web app the configuration is injected (so something like  IConfig in constructor) which would be preferable. I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

In our project we added the variables from the local config file to Application Settings in the Azure Portal.

Create the object like so: new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

And then you retrieve them as usual i.e. Configuration["Key"];

Comment: Ok thanks - how do I test this locally? In my previous web apps I had local app settings file that was overridden by app setting in Azure portal.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to go about it but what we did is basically "if (File.Exists(localSettingsFile)) //create local config; else //create azure config"

Comment: Thanks - I guess if it works..! I’ll do some investigation

Answer (score 1):

To access local appsettings in Azure Function(Whether it's on Azure or local debugging.), we can do as below:

```
public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
    return name + ": " +
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

More information for your reference: [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#environment-variables)

Comment: So this will either take from portal if exists else from appsettings.json? Sorry I’m not able to test anything until this evening otherwise I’d just give it a go! I’ll read the link when I have 5 mins... thanks!